# Fill listbox with images from combobox selected hard drive

Tags: c#, wpf, list, combobox, listbox

I still seem to be stuck on this on can't find a way to word it properly, I have a combobox which lists hard drives, which ever HDD is chosen should fill a listbox with images from that chosen HDD, the part I'm stuck on is how do I get my list to get files from the selected HDD from the combobox, instead of me just putting Enviroment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures etc which would elminate the purpose of having the combobox. I have a datatemplate and everything, just stuck on the list

Comment: You mean all images from all folders and their subfolders of a selected drive? Look at the `Enumerate` methods in [System.IO.Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx). You would have to recursively enumerate all folders and image files in drive.

Comment: I'm pretty noob here so do excuse me, I have a list which is to load all images, the list creates a new instance followed by a for each loop foreach(string filename in Directory.GetFiles((MyComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()))), each list box item is address like c:/ etc Im trying to convert that to a string then use that as the path to use directory.getfiles on, its at the begginning of directory.getfiles that I get object reference not set to an instance of a object, I was hoping you could help me there, thanks for the help so far

Answer (score 0):

One approach may be

```
<ComboBox Name="combo" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged" >
```

Then in code behind

```
    private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = combo.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
        if (item == null) return;
        var hdd = item.Content.ToString();
    }
```

Now you can use `hdd` to help the ListBox select the appropriate HHD items.

Comment: Personally I would avoid using code-behind like this. The whole point of WPF is that is facilitates the MVVM model which in turn allows you to do things like dependency injection and unit testing etc. The "correct" method is to bind to a model containing members for the hard drive list and currently selected hard drive etc and then add code to the setters to generate new lists etc in response to the user selecting things from the combo boxes.

Comment: @Mark Yeah, but why obfuscate the answer with MVVM+XAML. He's already on this path. In fact I suspect his null ref exception in `Directory.GetFiles((MyComboBox.SelectedItem...` is because MyComboBox has no selected item.

Comment: With all due respect the path he's on is the wrong one. My issue isn't so much about the use of MVVM as it is about the use of the data binding mechanism upon which WPF is based. I answered an almost identical question of Nathan's yesterday and it's clear he's still coming to terms with it (no offense Nathan, WPF has a very steep learning curve and it's something we all grapple with at the start). If you absolutely must use behind code then bind the window's data context to itself, at least that way you're using the proper mechanism and can easily re-factor it out later without too much pain.

Comment: Also I'm sorry Nathan if I appear to be standing on a soap-box yelling out personal opinions as to what you should or shouldn't be doing without actually answering your question. The problem is if you get off to a wrong start with WPF and don't "get" the whole WPF data binding concept (regardless of whether or not you use MVVM) then you're going to have a very difficult time understanding most of the WPF code out there or people's responses to future questions you may ask. If you need me to clarify the code I gave you yesterday then please let me know and I'll certainly do my best.

Comment: @Mark Well sir I disagree with your assessment. He said he was new to this, a complex answer tho more generally correct could lead to even more confusion at this juncture. Why tell a 7 yr old Integrate x^2 + y^2 when pi*r*^2 will suffice for the area of a circle. A modicum of early success (imo) goes a long way.

Comment: on paper like a diagram, I get the concept of mvvm but when it comes to coding it, its confusing, I got a little understanding on binding (least more than I used to) when I look at the code of a model and the code of a view model they look simular

Comment: a part of me actually wants to give up but that one thing that keeps me back to coding is that your in control of making tools that benefit your needs

Comment: Don't give up you are right, coders are in control. Understanding MVVM is worth it take it in small chunks. The way I did it was to focus on the binding concept between View(essentially XAML) and ViewModel(The binding code-behind + dependency properties). The WPF binding is what decouples View from VM, and makes it different from the old MVP etc. Then I figured out how the Model fit in. A great place to start is [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx]